# Sorting n objects when binary relationships between any two numbers are given

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Problem Statement: Sort n objects  a1,a2...an  when binary relationships between any two number are given.

Say for eg 5 objects a1,a2,a3,a4 & a5

```
a1 < a5
a4 < a2
a3 < a5
a2 < a1
a1 < a3
```

So the order would be   a4 a2 a1 a3 a5 
Any algorith to do this

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting.

Comment: Your table doesn't match the problem description. The problem description says that the relationship is defined between any two numbers, so your table should have 15 entries, not 5. If you have 15 entries, then this is just sorting with a custom comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to keep a matrix `relationships[x, y] = true if x < y` and use that matrix as the comparison function in your favorite sorting algorithm.

Topological sorting will probably be more efficient however.

Comment: From a brief look at Wikipedia, it looks like topological sort is `O(|V| + |E|)`, thus `O(n + n^2) = O(n^2)` if given all relationships, thus **not** more efficient than `O(n log n)` sort. But that said, constructing the matrix will also take `O(n^2)`, so, asymptotically, it won't make a difference (although the faster `O(n log n)` sort should also be less effort to implement).